# Skip List view when search returns 1 result - Third Party

Tags: search, extensions

My question is actually based on the excellent post response by Marius♦: [*Catalog Search: If only one result, show product view page insted of list view 1*](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54122/catalog-search-if-only-one-result-show-product-view-page-insted-of-list-view)

The question is - would this affect any search method, even if it is a third party module?

Is there a way of placing the redirect within the code for said module's search function?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the custom module, but if the module responds to the url `catalogsearch/result/index` yes it will be affected.
If the url is different then you will have to add a new observer in your `config.xml` class similar to the other 2 mentioned in the existing answer.