# Magento Change Search Result

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I have a website in magento, right now search results showing in product listing page, i want change the search result page into Product view page.

I don't know how to do this, please help me anyone?

Comment: Can you explain more want do you mean by product view page? You will get multiple products in result.

Comment: Hi..thanks for your reply ,       In case iam going to type exact product name or sku, so that product only i want display in product detail page instead of listing page.

Comment: magento version?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Comment: Actually what i want when ever searching means i want result in listing page, if i typed exact sku means i want display that product only in product detail page.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54122/catalog-search-if-only-one-result-show-product-view-page-insted-of-list-view  ===============================================                                     Above url work's fine for me, but only one this i have attribute like discontinued with options yes/no, if yes means it will go to product detail page, no means listing page so any one  help me